# Localhost subdomains and wildcard issues

Tags: apache, virtualhost, vhosts

I have setup on a xampp install a wildcard vhost on xampp in windows because I wanted to test some apps in localhost without having to add a too many lines to vhosts.conf for each and every app. I figured this would be the easiest and simplest way to do this was to add the following to my vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAlias *.localhost
       VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/%1/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/%1/"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/%1/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This let's me access superawesomeapp1 at the foldername in htdocs as a subdomain of localhost. So anything in foo is at `foo.localhost` and bar to `bar.localhost` and so on.
This worked well until I had an app that wanted the following added to vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName johnny.localhost
    ServerAlias johnny.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/heyjohnny/web"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/heyjohnny/web">
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/heyjohnny/web/bundles">
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`enter code here`
```

The vhost server alias overrides the latter, but I cannot figure out how to override the former short of commenting it out and manually mashing at the keys for every vhost I want to add which adds up after a while. I noticed it also overrode any attempt to redirect http to https. I might be running some of these things on localhost but I plan to use some of them over lan eventually. I attempted reordering the entries, putting the wildcard alias last but that didn't change anything. I'm most likely doing it wrong, but I'm open to suggestions.